# Using custom converter with rxandroid Completable

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-android

I have a problem using retrofit with rxandroid.
I've created a custom converter as below:

```
class CustomResponseConverter<T>(private val converter: Converter<ResponseBody, *>): Converter<ResponseBody, T> {

    override fun convert(value: ResponseBody): T? {
        // custom convert response here
    }
}
```

It's all working fine when i'm returning `Single` like this:

```
@GET("route")
fun simpleFetch(): Single<FetchData>
```

but when i try returning `Completable` like this:

```
@GET("route")
fun simpleFetch(): Completable
```

I found that the `convert` function doesn't get call. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's running into the same case as me, apparently according to retrofit team [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3481#issuecomment-710609459):

> Using Completable bypasses all converters, yes, and simply closes the response body so it is consumed. Since there is nowhere for the converted body to go with a Completable, there is no need to call it and perform conversion.

So I guess we'll just keep using `Single` on this case.